# Magento 2: Why I can't find this function: hasItemsCollection() in Quote Class?

Tags: magento2, quote

Magento version: 2.0.0

In `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote` line 1336 to 1354:

```
/**
 * Retrieve quote items collection
 *
 * @param bool $useCache
 * @return  \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function getItemsCollection($useCache = true)
{
    if ($this->hasItemsCollection()) {
        return $this->getData('items_collection');
    }
    if (null === $this->_items) {
        $this->_items = $this->_quoteItemCollectionFactory->create();
        $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor->process($this->_items);
        $this->_items->setQuote($this);
    }
    return $this->_items;
}
```

There is a function `hasItemsCollection()`, I can not find where or how it is defined. So, anybody know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically it does NOT exist because it is a Magic Methods which is defined in /lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DataObject.php

This method work similarly to `getXyz()` or `setXyz()`, but it's job is to check to see whether a property exist or not in the class.

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    switch (substr($method, 0, 3)) {
        case 'get':
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method, 3));
            $index = isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null;
            return $this->getData($key, $index);
        case 'set':
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method, 3));
            $value = isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null;
            return $this->setData($key, $value);
        case 'uns':
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method, 3));
            return $this->unsetData($key);
        case 'has':
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method, 3));
            return isset($this->_data[$key]);
    }
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
        new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('Invalid method %1::%2(%3)', [get_class($this), $method, print_r($args, 1)])
    );
}
```